# Magento2 certification retake questions same as 1st attempt?

Tags: magento2, certification

I was failed **magento2** professional developer **exam**, I'm studying on these days to **2nd attempt**. Anyone know do we have **similar set of questions** for 2nd attempt?

Comment: can you share the questions of first attempt?

Comment: @jafarpinjar Did you get question set for first attempt?

Comment: @Deeps, no dear, I am looking for it

Comment: I think the exam questions are randomly selected from a large set of questions. So most of the questions will be different. You may find some of the questions similar, but that will be quite rare.